# Communicating to the serial port of the Kenwood TH-D72A is seems nearly impossible. Why can't I read data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-serialport

This is (hopefully) the end of a god-awful journey. I have a long history of communicating with serial ports via tty terminal programs and it usually takes 5 mins to set them all up.

What am I trying do?

**1. Write commands to the TH-D72A via javascript** 
**2. Read data from the TH-D72A via javascript**

*Successes:*
A: Can read and write in python. However the TH-D72A get into a weird mode where it doesn't respond.
B: Contacted Kenwood Customer support and have a very lengthy discussion with them. Yet, I have put in 3 weeks of something that should take 5 mins. and they don't seem to understand what's wrong either.
C: This operational mode will be on Raspberry Pis but my dev OS is Mac OS.  I'm able to do the python scripts in either platform.

**Code**

I'm not sure if I **must** use a parser or simply read from the port.  port.read() does not display any data.  This code compiles but there are no data sent to the func:

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var util = require("util"); 
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline; 
var devicePath = '/dev/ttyUSB0';
var osvar = process.platform;
console.log(osvar);
if (osvar == 'darwin') {
    console.log("Using Mac OS");
    devicePath = '/dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART';
}else{ 
    devicePath = '/dev/ttyUSB0';
}

 const port = new SerialPort(devicePath, {
   baudRate: 9600,
   parity: 'none',
   stopBits: 1,
   dataBits: 8,
   flowControl: false
 }, function(err) {
   if (err){
     console.log('error: ', err.message);
     port.close();
 }});

 const parser = new Readline({delimiter: '\n'});
 port.pipe(parser);

 console.log('parser setup');

 parser.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log('data received: ', data);
 });


 port.on('data', function(data) { console.log('Date:' +data);
 });

 port.on('open', function() { console.log('Port Opened');
 });

 port.on('close', function() {  console.log('Port Closed');  
 });

 port.write('DISP\r\n');


router.get('/', function (req,res) { 
    res.render('terminal', { title: 'Terminal Page' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Other**

The projects are open at github: https://github.com/kcw-grunt/nodetest
And, I forked a module (npm) to add more methods: https://www.npmjs.com/package/th-d72-ax25

I hope there is some javascript guru that can see the problem (which must be really simple)

Comment: I'm curious if the module you forked works out with no modifications?  Are you sure that is the correct baud rate and all?

Answer (score 1):

**Background**
I have become a forensics specialist trying to figure why this simple task has taken literally **6 weeks**...and I have found a solution. I consider it a workaround but I can move forward with it to continue code my bigger solution

Each of my supporters have suggested that javascript was sound and I tend to agree with them. But, the system was not responding at all. This includes the serialport 2.0.6, 2.1.2 and even v 6.2.0.

This code actually works (as well as @psiphi75 said it should):

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(); 
var serialport = require('serialport');
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var devicePath = '/dev/ttyUSB2';

var port = new SerialPort( devicePath, { // change path
  baudrate: 9600
, function ( err ) {
  if ( err ) {
    console.error('error opening serial port:' , err);
  }
}
});

port.on('data', function(data) {

  console.log('Data:'+data)
});

port.write('KISS ON\r\n', function(err) {
  console.log('KISS ON Turned on');
});

port.write('RESTART\r\n', function(err) {
  console.log('Restarted');
});

port.on('open', function() {
  console.log('Port Opened');
});

port.on('closed', function() {
  console.log('Port Closed');
});

var start = Date.now();
setInterval(function() {
    var delta = Date.now() - start; // milliseconds elapsed since start
     // alternatively just show wall clock time:
    console.log(new Date().toUTCString());
    port.write('I\r\n');
}, 5000); // update  



router.get('/', function (req,res) { 
    res.render('terminal', { title: 'Terminal Page' });
});


module.exports = router;
```

The problem has actually been the Kenwood TH-D72A serial (USB) port.  In fact when using it in a dev enviroment, it remains in a state where it does not emit data after the second serialport 'connection'.  This is a serious bug Kenwood should fix especially that the HT is considered one of the most expensive on the market.

***The workaround has been to simply power cycle the TH-D72A each time a build + run is started.***

I may spend some time finding out if there is some persistent state causing this.  But, the code **restarts** the HT in each build..  This will be a serious problem for a non-tech user in the field let alone someone without 2 Raspberry Pis, a Linux, windows and Mac

Answer (score 0):

I've used SerialPort many times without issues ([gprs-signal-strength](https://github.com/psiphi75/gprs-signal-strength/blob/master/index.js), [super-duper-serial-gps-system](https://github.com/psiphi75/super-duper-serial-gps-system/blob/master/src/serialgps.js). Here is some example code.

*Note:* These use SerialPort v2.0.x.  Which looks like it used the `new SerialPort.SerialPort(...)` syntax as opposed to the udpated `new SerialPort(...)` syntax.

```
const port = new SerialPort.SerialPort('/dev/ttyS2', {
    baudrate: 115200,
    parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline( '\r\n' ) // you may just want \r or \n
}, function ( err ) {
    if ( err ) {
        console.error( 'Error opening GPRS serial port: ', err );
    }
} );

port.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for looking. I was warned not to use serialport 6.2.0.  Because my dev env (mac OS) and prod env (debian stretch) are different, I took the approach to keep updated. In  fact when I reverted to serial 2.1.2, my rpis crashed/were unhappy.

Comment: @hulkinggrunt, have you tried the above code with v6.0.x and updating the syntax?  Or changing the readline behaviour to use `ByteLength`.

Comment: I'm going to do that and get back to you.

Comment: I changed the bytelength method (adding the module) and this compiles:   

  const port = new SerialPort(devicePath, {
   baudRate: 9600,
   parity: 'none',
   stopBits: 1,
   dataBits: 8,
   flowControl: false
 }, function(err) {
   if (err){
     console.log('error: ', err.message);
     port.close();
 }});
 const parser = port.pipe(new ByteLength({length: 8}))

Comment: and this worked?  Or not?  If it's not working, then nodeserial is not getting data.  Then I would go back to Python or some other tool (I like minicom) to use the same parameters and make sure everything is the same.  I.e. make sure serial is working on the raspberry pi.

Comment: Did you follow the Johnny-Five Instructions?: https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport#raspberry-pi-linux.  Which I think would just be to install pigpio using `sudo apt-get install git pigpio`

Comment: I reviewed it but I have many moving parts here and ironically the RPi is the most stable. I reviewed Johnny5 and it looks like they are using Arduinos. But, the Kenwood is the real problem. I use my mac to test , push up the repo commit to master, have my RPis to fetch and move the head to the latest commit. then see if they behave.  Since I can't read from the port in either linux or unix/mac os I've avoided that alley....but I definitely., stared deeply in the abyss before strolling by

Comment: Sorry @psiphi75...bytelength strategy had no positive effect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174688/discussion-between-psiphi75-and-hulkinggrunt).

Comment: @psiphi75...Thanks so much for your patience and help.  I found the problem..it is the radio

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still trying to do this, I got it working with the following code and `serialport@7.1.5`:

```
const SerialPort = require("serialport");

const port = new SerialPort("/dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART", {
  baudRate: 9600,
  dataBits: 8,
  parity: "none",
  stopBits: 1,
  rtscts: true
});
```

I think the trick is to turn on hardware flow control with `rtscts: true`.